# Querying multiple database servers?

Tags: sql

I am working on a database for a monitoring application, and I got all the business logic sorted out. It's all well and good, but one of the requirements is that the monitoring data is to be completely stand-alone.

I'm using a local database on my web-server to do some event handling and caching notifications. Since there is one event row per system on my monitor database, it's easy to just get the id and query the monitoring data if needed, and since this is something only my web server uses, integrity can be enforced externally. Querying is not an issue either, as all the relationships are one-to-one so it's very straight forward.

My problem comes with user administration. My original plan had it on yet another database (to meet the requirement of leaving the monitoring database alone), but I don't think I was thinking straight when I thought of that. I can get all the ids of the systems a user has access to easily enough, but how then can I efficiently pass that to a query on the other database? Is there a solution for this? Making a chain of ors seems like an ugly and buggy solution.

I assume this kind of problem isn't that uncommon? What do most developers do when they have to integrate different database servers? In any case, I am leaning towards just talking my employer into putting user administration data in the same database, but I want to know if this kind of thing can be done.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few ways to accomplish what you are after:

- Use concepts like linked servers (SQL Server - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx)
- Individual connection strings within your front end driving the database layer
- Use things like replication to duplicate the data

Also, the concept of multiple databases on a single database server instance seems like it would not be violating your business requirements, and I investigate that as a starting point, with the details you have given.